# Vimeo API: upload video files using resumable approach

Tags: file-upload, vimeo-api, tus

I'm following the Vimeo api's guide about resumable uploads (https://developer.vimeo.com/api/upload/videos#resumable-tus-upload). 
I get a response after the first request but I get an `undefined` response for the second request (step 2. Upload the video file). 
The guide tells to PATCH the binary data of the video file to the URL from upload.upload_link. I'm using `readAsBinaryString()` to convert the video file to binary data (I have tried also `readAsArrayBuffer()` but with the same result. What am I possibly doing wrong?
This is the code:

```
var reader = new FileReader();

$.ajax({
  'url': 'https://api.vimeo.com/me/videos',
  'type': 'POST',
  'headers': {
    'Accept': 'application/vnd.vimeo.*+json;version=3.4',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'Authorization': 'bearer ' + accessToken
  },
  "data": JSON.stringify({ 
    "upload" : {
      "approach" : "tus",
      "size" : fileSize

    }
  }),
  'success': function (result) {
    $.ajax({
      'url': result.upload.upload_link,
      'type': 'PATCH',
      'headers': {
        'Tus-Resumable': '1.0.0',
        'Upload-Offset': 0,
        'Content-Type': 'application/offset+octet-stream'
      },
      'data': reader.readAsBinaryString(fileContent),
      'success': function (result) {
        console.log(result)
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this working in my ReactJs application. Looks like you are missing the reader.onload() method - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/onload

I am saving the result of reader.readAsArrayBuffer to state.binaryData. I then pass binaryData into my axios/fetch request as data. It is working and i successfully uploaded video.

```
const reader = new FileReader();
const fileSize = e.target.files[0].size;
reader.onload = r => {
  this.setState({ binaryData: r.target.result, fileSize });
};
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(e.target.files[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have been working with same right now. I think when call Patch at that time it's not sure that your binary data of file is converted,

so to be sure you have to put that call into `reader.onload`. so it's been sure about binary data.

`readAsBinaryString` is deprecated. so you can use `readAsArrayBuffer`.
[Why is readAsBinaryString() deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55836771/why-is-readasbinarystring-deprecated)